# Query to retrieve index details for a particular column in all tables

Tags: mysql, index, mysql-5.6, information-schema

There is a column `created_at` in most of tables.

I would like to get the details if that field exists in the table and it is not indexed.

Is there any thing can be done with the information_schema to get this checked?

I'm using MySQL 5.6

Answer (score 1):

To check the column properties you can run the query

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = 'your_schema_name' 
AND COLUMN_NAME = 'created_at';
```

This will list all the **tables in your schema with the columns created_at**. Here you can check some of the column properties including the `COLUMN_KEY` with values `PRI`, `UNI`, `MUL`.

For a detailed view of the table index run the below query against the tables returned by the first query.
`SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name;`

Answer (score 0):

You need to examine one of the following:

- [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/key-column-usage-table.html)
- [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/statistics-table.html)

## EXAMPLE #1

- You have a table called `mydb.mytable`
- You have a columns called `mycolumn`
- You want to know if `mycolumn` is indexed at all

#### Query #1

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE table_schema='mydb'
AND table_name='mytable'
AND column_name='mycolumn';
```

#### Query #2

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS
WHERE table_schema='mydb'
AND table_name='mytable'
AND column_name='mycolumn';
```

## EXAMPLE #2

- You want to know if `mycolumn` is indexed at all
- You do not know which table has an index on that column

#### Query #1

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE column_name='mycolumn';
```

#### Query #2

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS
WHERE column_name='mycolumn';
```

## EXAMPLE #3

You want to know which table has a column called `mycolumn` that is not indexed anywhere

```
SELECT A.table_schema,A.table_name FROM
(
    SELECT table_schema,table_name
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
    WHERE column_name='mycolumn'
) A
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT table_schema,table_name
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
    WHERE column_name='mycolumn'
) B USING (table_schema,table_name)
WHERE B.table_schema IS NULL;
```

Comment: I tried: `create table testing ( created_at char(8) not null ); create index x1 on testing ( created_at );` but there is no information in information_schema.key_column_usage. This was for 10.1.26-MariaDB so there might be a difference from MySQL.